# Python program prints an extra empty line when reading a text file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, text

I'm using python 3.3. I have a text file with three lines of text, as an example. I want to select a number and it will display the contents of that line number. For some reason, it prints the line I want, and prints an empty line below it.

The text file looks like this:

```
AAPL,Apple,700
P,Pandora,32
MW,Men's Warehouse,54.32
```

The output in the interpreter I get if i is 2:

```
>>
P,Pandora,32

>>
```

And the code is here:

```
line_number = int(input('Enter the line number: '))
with open('C:/Python33/myprogramtests/filewrite1.txt') as f:
    i = 1
    for line in f:
        if i == line_number:
            break
        i += 1
    print (line)
```

I did try a comma after print (line) but it didn't work.
I'm guessing I'm missing some bit of code that would print just the line and not an extra whitespace line.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? It really helps to notice problems as yours. Use eg. Eclipse. Put breakpoint on line 2 and run in debug mode. Press F6 to continue. You may sneak a peek variable values in parameters window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should provide an `end=''` to `print` to suppress the automatic behaviour of adding the equivalent of `\n` to output.

I'd also remove the counting logic and use `islice` to extract the line you wish, eg:

```
from itertools import islice

line_number = int(input('Enter the line number: '))
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    print(next(islice(fin, line_number - 1, line_number), ''), end='')
```

If you wanted to use the count approach, then you can use `enumerate` starting at 1, eg:

```
for idx, line in enumerate(fin, start=1):
    if idx == line_number:
        print(line, end='')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative way to do it. Is itertools a built-in module?

Answer (score 3):

`print` adds `\n` and `\r` at the end of the string, and considering the line you've read already has a new line at the end, that's the behaviour. You can use instead:

```
print(line, end="")
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "strip()" method that removes excess whitespace. In your case:
print(line.strip())

Or done with an assignment:
line = line.strip()
print(line)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the trailing new line of the string, you can use rstrip('\n'):

```
print line.rstrip('\n')
```